# Expanding System.Object[] for Export to CSV

Tags: powershell

Hello again and sorry!

To keep it really short. What am i doing wrong?
Im attempting to export a list of users filtered by using a customobject to a CSV and it outputs it into the same block. Is there no way to change this? I only ask because, all the other pages ive looked at it keeps telling me to use `-join`, to join them as strings which does the exact same thing. Is it not possible to output it as multiple rows for each user?

```
$GPMem = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity security.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
[array]$TPpl = $GPMem | Where-Object {$_ -like "T*"} 
[array]$RPpl = $GPMem | Where-Object {$_ -like "r*"} 
[array]$CPpl = $GPMem | Where-Object {$_ -like "c*"} 

[pscustomobject]@{

    TPeople = (@($TPpl) |Out-String).Trim() 
    TPCount = $TPpl.Count
    RPeople = (@($RPpl) |Out-String).ToString()
    RPCount = $TPpl.Count
    CPeople = $CPpl
    CPCount = $TPpl.Count


    } | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\abraham\Desktop\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

[image]

Comment: usually i use `-join ';'` to join the values with semicolons.

Comment: @Lee, right. It does the same thing in regards to outputting the value in the same box. Is it not possible to have it output to a new row/box?

Comment: if you want multi-row output for JUST that column, try using a `cr/lf` for the delimiter instead of a colon. that will make a non-standard CSV file, but i presume that is acceptable in this case.

Comment: @Lee, care to explain further? im not familiar with that but, i wouild like to do it for every system object.

Comment: please see my Answer for how to use `-join` and a newline to give you a multiline CSV column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create 3 more arrays for the count (each array will be exported to a column), then find the array with the most count and generate a psobject for each line.

```
[array]$TPpl = @("T1" ,"T2", "T3")
[array]$TPpl_count = @($TPpl.Count)
[array]$RPpl = @("R1" ,"R2", "R3", "R4")
[array]$RPpl_count = @($RPpl.Count)
[array]$CPpl = @("C1" ,"C2", "C3", "C4","C5")
[array]$CPpl_count = @($CPpl.Count)


$leng = [array]$TPpl.Count,$RPpl.Count,$CPpl.Count
$max = ($leng | measure -Maximum).Maximum

$csv = for($i=0;$i -lt $max;$i++){

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
    "TPeople" = $(if ($TPpl[$i]) { $TPpl[$i]})
    "TPCount" = $(if ($TPpl_count[$i]) { $TPpl_count[$i]})
    "RPeople" = $(if ($RPpl[$i]) { $RPpl[$i]})
    "RPCount" = $(if ($RPpl_count[$i]) { $RPpl_count[$i]})
    "CPeople" = $(if ($CPpl[$i]) { $CPpl[$i]})
    "CPCount" = $(if ($CPpl_count[$i]) { $CPpl_count[$i]})
    }
}

$csv | Export-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

result:

[image]

your final code should be:

```
$GPMem = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity security.group | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
[array]$TPpl = $GPMem | Where-Object {$_ -like "T*"} 
[array]$RPpl = $GPMem | Where-Object {$_ -like "r*"} 
[array]$CPpl = $GPMem | Where-Object {$_ -like "c*"}
[array]$TPpl_count = @($TPpl.Count)
[array]$RPpl_count = @($RPpl.Count)
[array]$CPpl_count = @($CPpl.Count)


$leng = [array]$TPpl.Count,$RPpl.Count,$CPpl.Count
$max = ($leng | measure -Maximum).Maximum

$csv = for($i=0;$i -lt $max;$i++){

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
    "TPeople" = $(if ($TPpl[$i]) { $TPpl[$i]})
    "TPCount" = $(if ($TPpl_count[$i]) { $TPpl_count[$i]})
    "RPeople" = $(if ($RPpl[$i]) { $RPpl[$i]})
    "RPCount" = $(if ($RPpl_count[$i]) { $RPpl_count[$i]})
    "CPeople" = $(if ($CPpl[$i]) { $CPpl[$i]})
    "CPCount" = $(if ($CPpl_count[$i]) { $CPpl_count[$i]})
    }
}

$csv | Export-Csv C:\Temp\test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I would've never, and i mean, never, have come up with that. Im just exhausted on why it has to be so complicated to do this and, i wont lie to you. Im a little lost looking at the code but, it works. Now im trying to break it down line by line trying to figure it our. Thank you.

Comment: and i stuck with `[pscustomobject]` which placed the objects in order

Answer (score 3):

here is how to insert a `;`  OR newline into the values of a column ... [*grin*]

```
$ThingList = @('One Thing', 'Two Thing', 'Three Thing')

$ThingList -join '; '
'=' * 20
$ThingList -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
```

output ...

```
One Thing; Two Thing; Three Thing
====================
One Thing
Two Thing
Three Thing
```

Comment: Im running PS 5.0 and gave it a shot, and it didn't create a new line in the csv

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - there are other ways to represent a newline. try the powershell escaped `n` or `r` or the two combined. i cannot show them as such since the escape char in PoSh is a backtick ... [*grin*]

Comment: I think replacing the environment.newline with \n will do the job

Comment: @AsadBlum - the `\` character is NOT an escape char in normal PoSh. the backtick, tho, IS an escape char for this type of use case. [*grin*]